# Drop an image in a div and display a preview, using Angular6

Tags: angular, html, drag-and-drop, angular6

I want to drag and drop an image in a `div` and in the same div, I would like to display a preview of that image.

I have created a simple vanilla JS/HTML5 code that I am now trying to reform to Angular 6 .

This is my code so far

```
<div id="imageDrop" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" #imageDrop>

@ViewChild('imageDrop') imageDrop; 

  allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    this.checkfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }

  checkfiles(files){    
    if (files.length>1){
      this.imageDrop.innerHTML="Only one image/time";       
      return;
    }   
    else
    {
      this.readfiles(files);
    }
  }

  readfiles(files){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =  (event) =>{
      console.log('readfiles event ===== ',event);
      var image = new Image();
      image.src = event.target.result;
      image.width = 50; 
      this.imageDrop.appendChild(image);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  }
```

All my issues are in the `readfiles`.

First, VScode says `Property result does not exist on type EventTarget`, about the `image.src = event.target.result;` line. I dont know how to fix this, since this is pretty much what I want to put in the `img.src`, to later append it. By the way, the console log prints an event , where an image is contained in the `event.target.result`

Second, even if I try to drop an image there and gets its preview, console says `ERROR TypeError: _this.imageDrop.appendChild is not a function`.

How can I proceed to get the image I just dropped and preview it in that `div` ? Thank you

Comment: Can you please edit your question to show us where `imageDrop` is initialised?

Comment: `imageDrop` is the id of the `div`, but it does not make any difference I guess, this is why I removed it from the JS also.

Comment: What do you mean you removed it from the js? It's there in the `onload` function as `this.imageDrop.appendChild(image);`

Comment: Ah, yeah, sorry for this. I ment the `files.length>1` part of the `checkfiles` function. Anyhow, check the updated question. `imageDrop` is the id of the `div`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should specify that the type of `event.target` is `FileReader`, which will the give you access to `result`.

Also, to get the `appendChild` function, you first need to access the `nativeElement`.

The following code should work:

```
  readfiles(files){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload =  (event) =>{
      console.log('readfiles event ===== ',event);
      var image = new Image();
      var fileReader = event.target as FileReader;
      image.src = fileReader.result;
      image.width = 50; 
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.appendChild(image);
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);
  }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer and the remarks, very helpful. By the way, [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347269/pass-image-from-filereader-to-form-inout-in-angular-6) is what I try to achieve, take a look, you maybe interested in.