# Pass image from FileReader to form input in Angular 6

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular6, image-uploading, angular-reactive-forms

I try to create an UI where there is a form with a couple of text fields, a `input type="file"` and a `div` that you can drop images to upload with the rest of the form.

**My goal / logic**

use the same `div` to either drop an image or click on it and open the folder explorer like the `input type="file"` behaves. Enabling clicking makes sense in small screens where it is practically impossible to "drag and drop". And since there is already a `input type="file"` in the form there is no reason to take the image from the `div` and append it to the form etc etc. I try to take the image that is dropped in the `div`, set it as a value in the `input type="file"` and submit the form once. (if user clicked on the `div` , then the `input type="file"` already has a value , so again I am free to submit the form again).

Here is the **code**

```
  <div id="imageDrop" (click)='imageInput.click()' (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" #imageDrop>
  </div> 
  <input type="file" formControlName="imageInput" required #imageInput id="imageInput" (change)='imageChange($event)' > <!-- use css to hide it -->
```

So, when `imageDrop` is clicked, actually call the `imageChange` via `(click)='imageInput.click()'`

This is the typescript in the component.

```
//imageUpload is the name of the reactive form
acceptedImageTypes = {'image/png': true,'image/jpeg': true,'image/gif': true};
@ViewChild('imageDrop') imageDrop; 

allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
     //clear in case we selected something before via click
    this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset();  
    this.imageDrop.innerHTML="";    
    this.checkfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }

  imageChange(event){    
    this.imageDrop.innerHTML="";   
    this.checkfiles(event.target.files);    
  }//imageChange

  checkfiles(files){      
    if (this.acceptedImageTypes[files[0].type] !== true){
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="Not an image";          
      return;   
    }
    else if (files.length>1){
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="Only one image/time";           
      return;   
    }    
    else { this.readfiles(files); }
  }//checkfiles

  readfiles(files){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let image = new Image();
    reader.onload =  (event) =>{
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="";                
      let fileReader = event.target as FileReader;
      image.src = fileReader.result;
      image.width = 150; 
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.appendChild(image);      
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);    

    if (this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.value==null) {
        //if its null then means that we dragging an img, so the previous image from the input file is deleted
        //now we got to put this image to the input file in order to submit the form
      this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset(files[0] );            
    }    
  }//readfiles

  imageUploadSubmitted(){
    //when form submit, for now just check image value to check if its the right one
    console.log('IMAGE VALUE SUBMIT = =  ',this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.value);
  }
```

**Errors**

When I try to drag/drop an image, I get this `ERROR DOMException: Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string` that points to this HTML line `<div id="imageDrop" (click)='imageInput.click()' (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" #imageDrop>` but I am sure it is related to the

```
if (this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.value==null) {
  this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset(files[0] );            
}
```

part of the `readfiles` function.

Any ideas how to fix this, so the file input can get a value and be then free to submit the form?

Thanks

Comment: @user184994 Sorry, you lost me. Set what to an empty string? The `imageInput` ? But, I want it to have the image as a value.

Comment: Sorry, I hadn't read the code properly. Can you create a StackBlitz with your code that reproduces the issue please?

Comment: By the way I replaced `this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset(files[0] ); ` with  `this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.setValue(files[0]); ` . `setValue` makes more sense here. I am trying to fix this and when I create a stackblitz I will let you know.

Comment: @user184994 This is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wzvlxm?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) I dont have a clue why it has `Template parse errors`, but at least this is the whole code and that gives me the problem. Thanks again

Answer (score 8):

Okay, the line giving you he error was `this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.setValue(files[0]);`

The reason is, the browser will prevent you from programmatically setting the file that way due to security problems.

Instead, you can use the `e.dataTransfer.files` directly:

```
let input = this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput as any;
input.files = files;
```

**[Here is a fork of your stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa3bek?file=src/app/app.component.ts)**

Comment: Hi again. Great catch, I would not think of it in a million years. But there is  a problem. If I drop the image and fill a name (the 2 required inputs for the form), the Submit button is still not activated, as if the form is not valid, so I guess the input file does not have a value? If I click and pick an image, everything works fine. Any suggestions? Thanks

Comment: I try to think if maybe there is another way to do this, instead of "switching" the file from the drop to the file input. Maybe when on drop fire the `imageInput` ? But this makes no sense because it will again open the folder explorer. Is there another default way to set the value of the file input?

Comment: Check [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-fa3bek?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) . Using `input.value` seems to work for both cases. Problem now is that the file input has two different kinds of values (check the console) . I guess I could fix that if I set as value the result of the read image, so I wrote the commented out code in the `readfiles` function. But this does not work, it gives an error about the `event.target.result`.

Comment: Sorry, [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-2frtxq?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: @codebot just remove anything from `drop(e)` function and keep it exactly  like `imageChange` function and you will get exactly same results on console

Comment: Is it possible to upload file in folder?

Answer (score 1):

What you are trying to do can't be achieve this way (cause of what every people said, security reason etc...).

To acheive what you want to do, an Angular Solution is to create a custom component working with [(ngModel)] formControlName by implementing the **ControlValueAccessor**.

By doing this you will be able to put what ever you want as value into the FormControl.

Implementing ControlValueAccessor is part of many tutorial : https://blog.angularindepth.com/never-again-be-confused-when-implementing-controlvalueaccessor-in-angular-forms-93b9eee9ee83

Here you can find some code of my own, an image-chooser working in a Form :

https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/blob/master/src/components/asi-image-chooser/asi-image-chooser.component.ts

example : https://ng-tools.asi.fr/views/showroom/asi-ngtools/components/asi-image-chooser