# Set the value of file input in Angular 6

Tags: angular, typescript, input, angular6

I am using Angular 6 and I want to get the image that is dropped in a `div` and set it as a value in the `input type="file"` of a form.

So, the user drops an image in the `div`, the file input gets that image as a value and then I can submit the form.

This is the code

```
<form [formGroup]="imageUpload" (ngSubmit)="imageUploadSubmitted()">
  <div id="imageDrop" (drop)="drop($event)" (dragover)="allowDrop($event)" #imageDrop></div> 

  <input type="file" formControlName="imageInput" required #imageInput id="imageInput"  >
  <label>
    <input type="text" formControlName="imageName" placeholder="name" required >
  </label>                      

  <button type="submit" [disabled]="!imageUpload.valid">Submit</button>
</form>
```

and the component is

```
  allowDrop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }

  drop(e) {
    e.preventDefault();  
    this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.reset();  
    this.imageDrop.innerHTML="";    
    let input = this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput as any;
    input.value = e.dataTransfer.files[0];  
    this.readfiles(e.dataTransfer.files);
  }

  readfiles(files){
    const reader = new FileReader();
    let image = new Image();
    reader.onload =  (event) =>{
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.innerHTML="";                
      let fileReader = event.target as FileReader;
      image.src = fileReader.result;
      image.width = 150; 
      this.imageDrop.nativeElement.appendChild(image);  
      /*if (this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput.value==null) {                
        let input = this.imageUpload.controls.imageInput as any;        
        input.value = event.target.result;  
      }  */
    };
    reader.readAsDataURL(files[0]);    

  }
```

The `input.value` in the `drop` always has a value, but I guess is the wrog type of value.  The submit button of the form is not active.

Then maybe I need to read the image to set it as a value, so I will transfer the logic in the `readfiles` - check the commented out code. This does not work, since I get an error no the `result` of the `input.value = event.target.result;` . The error is `Property result does not exist on type EventTarget`

How can I fix this and set the image as a file input value ?

Thanks

PS, here is the [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-5gstwa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts)

Answer (score 2):

what do you want to find as value in the imageInput formControl ?

A way to make it work is to change input.value to

```
input.setValue(e.dataTransfer.files[0]);
```

Like this the formControl will be correctly up to date and not INVALID anymore... BUT since you use an input file it will not work (it will tell you that he want a fileName)

But actually you don't really use the input file as an input file so you can change the input in the HTML by removing the type="file" and your form should work ;)

---

here you could find a image chooser of my own working with ngModel or formControlName and which can be init with base 64 : 
https://github.com/xrobert35/asi-ngtools/tree/angular6-compatibility/src/components/asi-image-chooser 
and a working demo here :
https://ng-tools.asi.fr/views/showroom/asi-ngtools/components/asi-image-chooser

Comment: Hi there. Thanks for the info. The issue is that I have tried using the `setValue` and get errors. In the stackblitz, if I try `setValue` I get `ERROR Error: The operation is insecure.` . Chrome says `Failed to set the 'value' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element accepts a filename, which may only be programmatically set to the empty string.` .  I did not test removing the `type="file"` because I want the `imageDrop` to be clickable and be able to call the `imageInput` file picker.

Comment: I was thinking about a solution but I can't actually see anything else than using an hidden input to store the data or like me create a component with ControlValueAccessor to make it work for formControlName and store the data you want

Comment: Also, I think [formidable](https://www.npmjs.com/package/formidable) needs  to see a `type="file"` to recognize the files in a form. So I cannot remove the `type="file"` at all. By the way, this is my [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52347269/pass-image-from-filereader-to-form-input-in-angular-6) , where this problem came from. It might help you understand better what I want to do and help you think a solution. Now, I will check your links and let you know. Thanks

Comment: Its fine, any solution you have just tell me, I am lost now, canot fix this, so any idea will be fine.